# Online advertising program where publishers (site owners) can choose ads?

Tags: advertising, google-adsense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self ads targeting](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8501/self-ads-targeting)

I'm wondering what online advertising programs there are out there where the site owner can chose which relevant ads to put on particular pages from a large selection of possible ads.  Is there such a thing? (As opposed to adsense style 'auto-relevance' which often produces poor results)

Comment: In my opinion this  is not an exact duplicate of that question.  The other question (and the only answer given) relates to user profiling. I'm not interested in user profiling, I only want to tailor the relevancy to the site content better.